# Error message with electron (node.js): binding.lstat(BaseLong)

Tags: node.js, npm, electron, node-modules

I've just started learning electron and created an app yesterday following a tutorial online. The app worked perfectly yesterday, but today I keep getting this error message:

```
    fs.js:1669
       binding.lstat(baseLong)
               ^
    Error: EINVAL: invalid argument, lstat 'C:Users\joe\OneDrive\Documents\test-app-electron
      at realpathSync (fs.js:1669:15)
      at Object.fs.realpathSync (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:330:24)
      at toRealPath (module.js:143:13)
      at Function.Module._findPath (module.js:192:22)
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:483:25)
      at Function.Module._load (module.js:437:25)
      at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
      at startup (bootstrap_node.js:167:16)
      at bootstrap_node.js:589:3
```

The error message goes on for some time, but I believe the above is the relevant part. I haven't done any changes to my computer, it just stopped working. The fs.js file is part of the "node-modules" folder and not a file I've written or edited anything in.

I then followed the instructions on this page: [writing your first electron app](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/first-app), which is just how to create a basic window using electron. I got the same error message. I downloaded an example app and tried running it: same error message.

I have tried uninstalling node_modules with `rm -r node_modules` and then reinstalling with `npm install`, with no luck.

Comment: Please add relevant codes and error details in the question itself, Do not give images of codes or errors, yet as a link unless its absolute necessary .

Comment: related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50070139/cant-run-electron-app-einval-invalid-argument-lstat/)?