# Can't run Electron app - EINVAL: invalid argument, lstat

Tags: electron

I'm getting the following error whenever I try to run my app:

[image: Screenshot]

My `package.json`:

```json
{
    "name": "SteamCMD-GUI",
    "productName": "SteamCMD GUI",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "main": "main.js",
    "author": "avi12",
    "scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "package": "asar pack \"SteamCMD GUI-win32-x64\" \"SteamCMD GUI.asar\"",
    "build-windows": "electron-packager . --platform=win32 --overwrite --out=release-builds --prune=true --icon=image/icon.ico --asar",
    "build-linux": "electron-packager . --platform=linux --overwrite --out=release-builds --prune=true --icon=image/icon.png --asar",
    "build-mac": "electron-packager . --platform=darwin --overwrite --out=release-builds --prune=true --icon=image/icon.icns --asar"
    },
    "dependencies": {
    "bignumber.js": "^5.0.0",
    "chokidar": "^1.7.0",
    "decompress": "^4.2.0",
    "electron": "^1.8.4",
    "electron-dl": "^1.11.0",
    "fs-jetpack": "^1.3.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "node-fetch": "^1.7.3",
    "onsenui": "^2.9.2",
    "sudo-prompt": "^7.1.1",
    "tooltip.js": "^1.2.0"
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: If this is an option for your project, could you install electron 2.0 beta instead?

Comment: I just tried uninstalling the current Electron version and installing specifically the latest current beta, 2.0.0 beta 8. It magically worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Searching for that error led me [here](https://github.com/atom/fuzzy-finder/issues/324), which suggests that it's a problem in `libuv`, an IO library used by Node. This issue is fixed in a later version of libuv, which is used by a later version of Node, which is used by a later version of Electron.

Updating to Electron 2.0 solves this issue.

Comment: Solved my problem indeed. The software is working again. Thank you a lot!